# Android: Not able to open csv file which is downloaded from DownloadManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-download-manager

I'm trying to open the **CSV** file downloaded using `DownloadManager` using the apps available in the phone. But I am not able to open it. The third party apps returns giving error **Toast messages** or **Alert Dialog** saying file location not found. But when, I open file manually, the app is getting opened normally. 
I have written below code for accessing the downloaded file and opening using Intent Chooser.

```
fun openDownloadedFile(referenceId : Long){
    if (downloadReference === referenceId)
    {
        val query = DownloadManager.Query()
        query.setFilterById(downloadReference)
        var downloadManager = activity?.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager?
        val c = downloadManager?.query(query)!!
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            val columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
            if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL === c.getInt(columnIndex))
            {
                var localUri:String = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
                if (localUri.substring(0, 7).equals("file://")) {
                    localUri =  localUri.substring(7);
                }
                var file = File(localUri);
                val fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(localUri)
                var mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension)
                if (mimeType != null)
                {
                    mimeType = "text/csv" // even after removing manual mime type it is not working.  
                    var intent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    //var file = File(localUri);
                    var absoluteFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    var uri = Uri.parse( "content:/"+absoluteFilePath);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                    intent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, mimeType);
                    try
                    {
                        // Add chooser to open file.
                        var intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Application");
                        startActivityForResult(intentChooser,1000);
                    }
                    catch (e:ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(“TAG”, "Download Failed.. status : "+c.getInt(columnIndex))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I chose, Microsoft Excel, it shows Cant open file error. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What Android Version?

Comment: @Andrew, Thanks for response, I am using Android 9 device to run this.

Comment: are you sure that csv file is in good condition itself? or have you tried opening it with other applications like WPS office?